# MYSQL PHP help with return a dataset

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey guys...I am trying to get some data based on a condition which I don't know how to write the code for.

My table looks like this:

```
id | meta_id | key      | value  
--   -------   ---        -----

1  | 1       | image    | 0

2  | 1       | path     | 1

3  | 1       | location | parent

4  | 2       | image    | 1

5  | 2       | path     | 2

6  | 2       | location | self
```

From this how can i return the meta_id that has key = image and value = 1 and value = 2..so you see i have value 2 times...can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I've understood

```
select * from table where key = 'image' and value in (1,2)
```

Comment: @Rick You should mark the answer as accepted - give @nick rulez the credit for providing you with an answer.